# Wave Function Collapse and Which Path Information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, wavefunction-collapse

From what I understand, wave function collapse occurs when a photon/wave/particle/whatevertheheckitis which was previously in a superposition of states, collapses to one state. Now, in a double slit experiment with single photons the photons could either pass through slit A or B. Now, once one figures out which path the photon takes, does this not necessarily collapse the wave function because the path which was previously in a superposition of two different states, collapses to one of the alternatives? I know that in the quantum eraser experiment the wave function is supposedly undisturbed, but if my reasoning is correct than during the experiment the wave function collapses. Am I right or do I have a misconception about what wave function collapse actually is?

Answer (score 0):

I will address this part:

> Am I right or do I have a misconception about what wave function collapse actually is?

IMO it is simpler to think in terms of wavefunctions as  solutions of differential equations whose complex conjugate squared gives the probability of finding a particle at (x,y,z) at time t. These solutions depend on the boundary conditions of the problem.  "Collapse" is a short hand way of saying "a specific instance has been measured in the probability distribution" .  Before, everything was "in potentia", after, a new solution with the new boundary conditions is necessary to describe the system.

Every time a detector or an element is entered in the experimental setup , a different solution appears, for example polarizers at slits, or on he way. In my view the experiment you [refer to](http://grad.physics.sunysb.edu/~amarch/) analyses the way the probability of scatter is built up.

Thinking of it mathematically, imo it is not surprising that a solution composed of sinusoidal functions will give interference functions, and also that affecting the phases of these functions ( as one does with the circular polarizer) can easily destroy interference patterns.